# Can you use custom typescript compiler with @typescript-eslint?

Tags: javascript, typescript, webpack, eslint, ts-loader

Basically, I have a webpack, package.json, tsconfig.json configs with, but it doesn't lint typescript files, for that you need `@typescript-eslint` package which can't configure custom compiler, are there any workarounds around this?

In my webpack config i use `ts-loader` and a `eslint-webpack-plugin`.

Comment: What compiler would you like to use instead of tsc?

Comment: @GOTO0 my own custom fork, but that can be applied to any other compiler that is not named `typescript`